# How can I build a tar from stdin?

Tags: tar

How can I pipe information into `tar` specifying the names of the file?

Comment: I think @geekosaur should be ticked because is the response which better match the question.

Comment: I've changed the selected answer you are right.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Something like:

```
tar cfz foo.tgz --files-from=-
```

But keep in mind that this won't work for all possible filenames; you should consider the `--null` option and feed `tar` from `find -print0`.  (The `xargs` example won't quite work for large file lists because it will spawn multiple `tar` commands.)

Comment: The "-T" option is not available on HP-UX.

Comment: @PeterMortensen install gnu tar or bsd tar? You'll need to check what name it might go by on the HP-UX app store...

Comment: Note that if you want to pipe through `sort` when using `find`'s `-print0` option and `tar`'s `--null` option as described, you will also need to supply the `-z` option to `sort`.

Answer (score 23):

As already pointed out by geekosaur, there is no need to pipe the output of `find` to `xargs` because it is possible to pipe the output of `find` directly to `tar` using `find ... -print0 | tar --null ...`.

Note the slight differences between `gnutar` and `bsdtar` in excluding the archive file though.

```
# exclude file.tar.gz anywhere in the directory tree to be tar'ed and compressed
find . -print0 | gnutar --null --exclude="file.tar.gz" --no-recursion -czf file.tar.gz --files-from -
find . -print0 | bsdtar --null --exclude="file.tar.gz" -n -czf file.tar.gz -T -

# bsdtar excludes ./file.tar.gz in current directory by default
# further file.tar.gz files in subdirectories will get included though
# bsdtar: ./file.tar.gz: Can't add archive to itself
find . -print0 | bsdtar --null -n -czf file.tar.gz -T -

# gnutar does not exclude ./file.tar.gz in current directory by default
find . -print0 | gnutar --null --no-recursion -czf file.tar.gz --files-from -
```

Comment: If finding in the current dir, then just using ../file.tar.gz as destination is sound enough.

Comment: Are "gnutar" and "bsdtar" literal?

Comment: @PeterMortensen ... they can be. `bsdtar` is available in linux for example, if you want to use BSD's tar(1).

Answer (score 19):

Extending [geekosaur answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5200173/471376):

```
find /directory | tar -cf archive.tar -T -
```

You can use stdin with the `-T` option.

Note that if you filter files using some condition (e.g. `-name` option) in general you need to **exclude directories** in the pipe, otherwise tar will process all their content, that is not what you want. So, use:

```
find /directory ! -type d -name "mypattern" | tar -cf archive.tar -T -
```

If you don't use `-type`, all the content of directories matching `"mypattern"` will be added !

Comment: I think this method is better that others, because you can pipe anything that outputs to stdout

Comment: You may want to consider being specific about the file types using `find`.  Specifically, I would do `find -type f`.  This will disclude symlinks, character devices, etc.
If you're interested in empty directories than `find -type f -o -type d`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979, is not better option to use `find -path dir/to/exclude -prune`? rather then avoiding dir by `type f`? And also, you say `mypattern`, but is not patter but rather globbin, for pattern is better `find -regex "patter"`

Comment: Rather than `-type f` to avoid directories, I recommend `! -type d`.  This has the advantage of **not** excluding other items such as symbolic links, fifos, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
find /directory > filename
tar -T filename -cf archive.tar
```

Comment: Will this work for all possible filenames (see [geekosaur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin/5200173#5200173))?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using pipe you could use backticks, e.g.:

```
tar cvzf archive.tgz `ls -1 *`
```

Instead of `ls -1 *` you can put any other command which produces list of needed to archive files

Comment: The only thing is that this will not work if the output of the ls command is longer than the shell's maximum allowed command line size. In such an event, you must do it as one of the other answers say; that permits the list to be arbitrarily long. Also, "find [...] -print0" allows you to create a tar file that has members with special characters, where as the ls method doesn't. This method just isn't as safe or universally applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The `tar` program has been implemented in a variety of ways. For example, on IBM's version of Unix, [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX), [`tar`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/tar.htm) uses the `-L` option rather than `-T`, and requires a file rather than allowing `-` to indicate stdin:

```
Usage: tar -{c|r|t|u|x} [ -BdDEFhilmopRUsvwZ ] [ -Number ] [ -f TarFil e ]
       [ -b Blocks ] [ -S [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ]
       [ -L InputList ] [-X ExcludeFile] [ -N Blocks ] [ -C Directory ] File ...
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvwZ[0-9] ] ]
       [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ]
       [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it different on WINDOWS. Do not use the `z` parameter because it causes the *"Can't add archive to itself"* error. In addition, if you dont use the ".tar" in the Zip file name (when using `z`) parameter, tar.exe will create a extensionless file inside the zip file, which is quite useless for most people.

And, i think most people want a single zip file with the files in it, not a zip file with a tar in it. So thats also a reasion not using the `z` parameter. However i talk about using tar in Windows, im not familar Linux, may it's different there. So in Windows:

To create a ZIP File inside a directory, with specific files in that directory, use:

```
tar.exe -cf MyZipFilename.zip file1.txt file2.jpg file3.xyz
```

To create a ZIP File inside a directory, with wildcard for files in that directory, use:

```
tar.exe -cf MyZipFilename.zip *.txt *.jpg *.xyzff
```

To let you view the zipped files, add the `v` parameter in between. Examples:

```
tar.exe -cvf MyZipFilename.zip file1.txt file2.jpg file3.xyz
```

or

```
tar.exe -cvf MyZipFilename.zip *.txt *.jpg *.xyzff
```

To create a ZIP File inside a directory, with all files in that directory, use:
(the trick is that --exclude is at the beginning)

```
tar.exe --exclude MyZipFilename.zip -cf MyZipFilename.zip *
```

Finally, i dont know why you want to use it, but if you want using `z` the command would be:

```
tar.exe --exclude MyZipFilename.tar.zip -cvzf MyZipFilename.tar.zip *
```

Just try it out

Comment: Doesn't answer the O.P.'s question:  how to use with stdin

Comment: tar-in-zip is the same principle as with tar-in-gzip, tar-in-bzip2, and tar-in-xz on linux. It also offers better compression comparing to normal zip due to single data stream ("solidity" in terms of rar/7z). But yes, I don't see how to create tar from stdin in your answer.