# Find files and tar them (with spaces)

Tags: linux, find, backup, tar

Alright, so simple problem here. I'm working on a simple back up code.  It works fine except if the files have spaces in them.  This is how I'm finding files and adding them to a tar archive:

```
find . -type f | xargs tar -czvf backup.tar.gz
```

The problem is when the file has a space in the name because tar thinks that it's a folder.  Basically is there a way I can add quotes around the results from find? Or a different way to fix this?

Comment: The best way to use `find ... | xargs ...` is to use the -print0/-0 parameter on each: `find -print0 ... | xargs -0 ...`. This will cause the filenames to be separated by a null character, which means you can have spaces or newlines or other weird stuff in your filenames and it will still work.

Comment: There is a problem with using xargs and tar this way when you have a large number of files, xargs will repeatedly invoke tar -c, and that will keep overwriting your archive, and the result is you won't have all the files you expect. See [this more detailed explanation](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/linux-unix/using-find-xargs-tar-create-huge-archive-cygwin-linux-unix) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12305562/296829) below.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | tar -czvf backup.tar.gz --null -T -
```

It will:

- deal with files with spaces, newlines, leading dashes, and other funniness
- handle an unlimited number of files
- won't repeatedly overwrite your backup.tar.gz like using `tar -c` with `xargs` will do when you have a large number of files

Also see:

- [GNU tar manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107)
- [How can I build a tar from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin), search for null

Comment: how would you do this if you wanted to pipe your find through sed a few times first? e.g. find . -print0 | sed /backups/d | tar....

Comment: Note that if have multiple conditions you need to add parenthesis. Otherwise the `-print0` applies to the last expression only. E.g. `find . \( -type f -o -name '*.c' \) -print0 | ...`

Comment: For fun, here's a Windows version of this using cygwin: `c:\cygwin\bin\find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*(sln^|vcxproj^|filters)$' -print0 | c:\cygwin\bin\tar -cvf MS_Projects.tar --null -T -`

Comment: @Steve can you please explain what is '-' option at the end of tar command. I cannot find it in GNU tar's man page.

Comment: Sure thing, it's a parameter to `-T`, and it means read the file names from standard input: If you give a single dash as a file name for `--files-from', (i.e., you specify either --files-from=- or -T -), then the file names are read from standard input

Comment: What does the `--null`?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen it handles the null-separated file names generated by the `-print0` arg to `find`, which makes all this able to handle filenames with spaces, newlines, etc.

Answer (score 17):

There could be another way to achieve what you want. Basically,

1. Use the *find* command to output path to whatever files you're looking for. Redirect *stdout* to a filename of your choosing.
2. Then tar with the -T option which allows it to take a list of file locations (the one you just created with find!)

   ```
   find . -name "*.whatever" > yourListOfFiles
   tar -cvf yourfile.tar -T yourListOfFiles
   ```

Comment: There is an answer here on how to handle filenames with newlines in them: https://superuser.com/a/513319/151261

Comment: this answer was the right one for me, because I needed to _edit_ the list before feeding it into `tar`. The first `man` page of `tar` looks like it gives an overview of the available options (so I stopped there), but there are many more...

Answer (score 8):

Try running:

```
    find . -type f | xargs -d "\n" tar -czvf backup.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not:

```
tar czvf backup.tar.gz *
```

Sure it's clever to use find and then xargs, but you're doing it the hard way.

Update: Porges has commented with a find-option that I think is a better answer than my answer, or the other one: `find -print0 ... | xargs -0 ....`

Comment: My full code will back up only items that are modified in the past day. Since its a daily back up I don't want to have repeated information to save on file size (I also have a full back up every 15 days).

Comment: To make this a better SO question, I would ask the question about "reliably using find, xargs, and tar together". Your title and question don't really specify that you need find and xargs, and yet you do.

Comment: `xargs ... tar c ...` will overwrite the first archive created if the list of files is too long and `xargs` will execute `tar` for second time! To avoid overwriting you can use `xargs -x` but then the archive could be incomplete. Alternative could be to first `tar c ...` and then possibly repeatedly `tar r ...`. (my contribution to the reliability :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple files or directories and you want to zip them into independent `*.gz` file you can do this. Optional `-type f -atime`

```
find -name "httpd-log*.txt" -type f -mtime +1 -exec tar -vzcf {}.gz {} \;
```

This will compress

```
httpd-log01.txt
httpd-log02.txt
```

to

```
httpd-log01.txt.gz
httpd-log02.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

Would add a comment to [@Steve Kehlet post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305562/3472383) but need 50 rep (RIP).

For anyone that has found this post through numerous googling, I found a way to not only find specific files given a time range, but also NOT include the relative paths OR whitespaces that would cause tarring errors. (THANK YOU SO MUCH STEVE.)

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -mtime 0 -printf "%f\0" | tar -czvf /dir/zip.tar.gz --null -T -
```

1. `.` relative directory
2. `-name "*.pdf"` look for pdfs (or any file type)
3. `-type f` type to look for is a file
4. `-mtime 0` look for files created in last 24 hours
5. `-printf "%f\0"` Regular `-print0` OR `-printf "%f"` did NOT work for me. From man pages:

> This quoting is performed in the same way as for GNU ls. This is not the same quoting mechanism as the one used for -ls and -fls. If you are able to decide what format to use for the output of find then it is normally better to use '\0' as a terminator than to use newline, as file names can contain white space and newline characters.

6. `-czvf` create archive, filter the archive through gzip , verbosely list files processed, archive name

Edit 2019-08-14:
I would like to add, that I was also able to use essentially use the same command in my comment, just using tar itself:

```
tar -czvf /archiveDir/test.tar.gz --newer-mtime=0 --ignore-failed-read *.pdf
```

Needed `--ignore-failed-read` in-case there were no new PDFs for today.

Answer (score 2):

Why not give something like this a try: `` tar cvf scala.tar `find src -name *.scala` ``

Answer (score 2):

Another solution as seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/513304):

```
find var/log/ -iname "anaconda.*" -exec tar -cvzf file.tar.gz {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution seem to be to create a file list and then archive files because you can use other sources and do something else with the list.

For example this allows using the list to calculate size of the files being archived:

```
#!/bin/sh

backupFileName="backup-big-$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")"
backupRoot="/var/www"
backupOutPath=""

archivePath=$backupOutPath$backupFileName.tar.gz
listOfFilesPath=$backupOutPath$backupFileName.filelist

#
# Make a list of files/directories to archive
#
echo "" > $listOfFilesPath
echo "${backupRoot}/uploads" >> $listOfFilesPath
echo "${backupRoot}/extra/user/data" >> $listOfFilesPath
find "${backupRoot}/drupal_root/sites/" -name "files" -type d >> $listOfFilesPath

#
# Size calculation
#
sizeForProgress=`
cat $listOfFilesPath | while read nextFile;do
    if [ ! -z "$nextFile" ]; then
        du -sb "$nextFile"
    fi
done | awk '{size+=$1} END {print size}'
`

#
# Archive with progress
#
## simple with dump of all files currently archived
#tar -czvf $archivePath -T $listOfFilesPath
## progress bar
sizeForShow=$(($sizeForProgress/1024/1024))
echo -e "\nRunning backup [source files are $sizeForShow MiB]\n"
tar -cPp -T $listOfFilesPath | pv -s $sizeForProgress | gzip > $archivePath
```

Comment: One liner for this?

Answer (score 0):

Big warning on several of the solutions (and your own test) :

When you do : anything | xargs something

xargs will try to fit "as many arguments as possible" after "something", but then you may end up with multiple invocations of "something".

So your attempt:   find ... | xargs tar czvf file.tgz
may end up overwriting "file.tgz" at each invocation of "tar" by xargs, and you end up with only the last invocation! (the chosen solution uses a GNU -T special parameter to avoid the problem, but not everyone has that GNU tar available)

You could do instead:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rvf backup.tar
gzip backup.tar
```

Proof of the problem on cygwin:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ seq 1 10000 | sed -e "s/^/long_filename_/" | xargs touch 
    # create the files
$ seq 1 10000 | sed -e "s/^/long_filename_/" | xargs tar czvf archive.tgz
    # will invoke tar several time as it can'f fit 10000 long filenames into 1
$ tar tzvf archive.tgz | wc -l
60
    # in my own machine, I end up with only the 60 last filenames, 
    # as the last invocation of tar by xargs overwrote the previous one(s)

# proper way to invoke tar: with -r  (which append to an existing tar file, whereas c would overwrite it)
# caveat: you can't have it compressed (you can't add to a compressed archive)
$ seq 1 10000 | sed -e "s/^/long_filename_/" | xargs tar rvf archive.tar #-r, and without z
$ gzip archive.tar
$ tar tzvf archive.tar.gz | wc -l
10000 
  # we have all our files, despite xargs making several invocations of the tar command
```

Note: that behavior of xargs is a well know diccifulty, and it is also why, when someone wants to do :

```
find .... | xargs grep "regex"
```

they intead have to write it:

```
find ..... | xargs grep "regex" /dev/null
```

That way, even if the last invocation of grep by xargs appends only 1 filename, grep sees at least 2 filenames (as each time it has: `/dev/null`, where it won't find anything, and `the filename(s)` appended by xargs after it) and thus will always display the file names when something maches "regex". Otherwise you may end up with the last results showing matches without a filename in front.