# How to exclude big files while compressing a directory with tar

Tags: linux, command-line, gzip, tar, compression

I want to compress a directory in Linux. I created a **tar.gz** that it turns to be a big file, due to the reason that the directory contains some *.o files and some pdf files.

Is there any way to compress a directory but exclude files **larger than a predefined SIZE?** There is a --exclude argument in tar command, however I would like to reject files larger than 1 MB. This is the constrain, not the name of the file.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> find ./myRep/ -type f -size -1024k | xargs tar cfvz myArchive.tar

In a word, first part of this expression construct a list of files that size is lower than 1024k recursively from ./myRep/ and second part create tar/gzip archive.

Comment: This might invoke tar repeatedly. Have a look at `find . -print0 | tar --null -T - ...` (from tar manual: "If you give a single dash as a file name for ‘--files-from’, (i.e., you specify either --files-from=- or -T -), then the file names are read from standard input. ")

Answer (score 4):

Based on Jan-Philip Gehrcke's response:

```
find . -type f -size -1024k -print0 | tar -czf --null -T - -f archive.tar.gz
```

for files less than 1M. Tested on OS X and Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: On debian squeeze I had this error :  
`tar: Multiple archive files require '-M' option`  
  
But it worked with something like :  
`find . -type f -size -100k | tar -cz -f test.tgz -T -`

Comment: @Fluxine Couldn't get that to work either. Had to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5891866/63736 and ended up with `find . -type f -size 1M -print0 | tar -vzcf backup.tar.gz --null -T -`

Comment: The `...| tar c --null -T - ` solution works nicely on arbitrarily long file lists, but has a minor drawback: it stores the whole file list in the memory. If you have lots of small files, then that may be a problem.

Comment: I am getting a long print-out of files like
`./file1\n./file1./file3\n` and an error `Cannot stat: File name too long
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors` on Ubuntu

Comment: It can be fixed by including `-print0`, as described in [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/148020/using-find-and-tar-with-files-with-special-characters-in-the-name/148021#148021)

Answer (score 1):

The `...| tar c --null -T -` solution above is the best if you have adequate memory (i.e. the file list fits into your memory easily (in most cases, this is true)). However, xargs *does* have a place if you are memory-constrained, but you have to use it appropriately so that the multiple tar invocations have no ill effect.

To compress, you may use:

```
find . -type f -size -1024k | xargs tar c | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

This results in a file of concatenated tar archives, gzipped together into the resulting file (you may also use `cz` and omit `| gzip` as concatenating gzip archives is still valid gzip, but you lose a tiny bit of compression, or quite a bit of compression if you use bzip2 or xz instead of gzip).

To extract the resulting file you *have* to use the `--ignore-zeros` or `-i` option of tar to not only extract the first archive:

```
tar xizf archive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a combination of find (with its -size flag) and xargs to pass it into tar.

Something like:

```
find . -size -100k -print | xargs tar cvf archive.tar
```

for files less than 100k. See man find for the other size options