# TAR-ing on-the-fly

Tags: bash, unix, compression, tar, on-the-fly

I'm trying to fetch all files within all directories on our SAN. I'm starting with my local to test out how I want to do it. So, at my Documents directory:
    `ls -sR > documents_tree.txt`

With just my local, that's fine. It gives the exact output I want. But since I'm doing it on our SAN, I'm going to have to compress on-the-fly, and I'm not sure the best way of doing this. So far I have:
    `ls -sR > documents_tree.txt | tar -cvzf documents_tree.tgz documents_tree.txt`

When I try to check the output, it is impossible for me to un-tar the file using `tar -xvf documents_tree.tar` after I have gunzipped it.

So, what is the correct way to compress on-the-fly? How can I accurately check my work? Will this work when performing the same process on a SAN?

Comment: You're not tarring the files, you're just tarring the list of filenames. Is that what you really want?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? The snippet you show writes the output of `ls -sR` to a file and simultaneously starts a `tar` process that writes this file to a gzipped tar archive. You have a race between `ls` and `tar` on whether the former finishes before the latter start reading the file. I'm not sure what the interplay between the redirection and pipeline is (they both act on stdout of `ls`). If you just want to archive a directory, wouldn't `tar czvf directory.tgz directory/` do the trick?

Comment: There's nothing special about doing this on a SAN. The SAN just looks like ordinary files to applications.

Comment: By the way: never use the output of `ls` for anything but human reading. Use `find` instead, or `find -print0` if you may have strange filenames.

Comment: See the accepted answer on this question [find-files-and-tar-them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891866/find-files-and-tar-them-with-spaces)

Comment: @Barmar @RolandW Thanks. I don't need to tar the actual files, just a list of the files and directories. The output I see from `ls -sR` is exactly what I want. The point of the rest of it is that the SAN is huge, so even if its just a list of all of it, I'll want to compress the output of the `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `tar` to compress a single file, just use `gzip`:

```
ls -sR | gzip > documents_tree.txt.gz
```

You can then use `gunzip documents_tree.txt` to uncompress it, or tools like `gzcat` and `zless` to view it without having to uncompress it first.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I wish `ls` had a verbose mode....I dont know if its actually doing anything, or this san is actually that huge.

Comment: You could use `ls -sR | tee /dev/tty | gzip > documents_tree.txt.gz`. Then you'll see the `ls` output in parallel with it being written to the gzip file.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon your comment on the OP and using your initial command, the following works for me:

ls -sR > documents_tree.txt && tar -cvzf documents_tree.tgz documents_tree.txt