# GIT: How to export all locally ignored files to other directory?

Tags: git, bash, command-line

Is there a command a way or a script that can let me export all the ignored git directories and files in my .gitignore file to a folder of my choice preserving the directory structure?

I can get the whole list using this command:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=[PATH_TO_GITIGNORE_FILE] -o
```

But I wasn't able to figure out how to do a mass export on a folder of my choice.

Comment: This lists files that are marked for exclusion, but are included anyway. For example, I generate a bunch of `.png`s, and have `*.png` in my `.gitignore`, but a selected few `.png` *are* under git's control, not generated. This command lists those only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course use **`tar`**. Since you generate the list of files already, see this question: [How can I build a tar from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin) on constructing an archive from the file list.

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of completeness here is the command:

`git ls-files -i --exclude-from=[PATH_TO_GITIGNORE_FILE] -o | tar cfz PATH_TO_TGZ -T -`