# How to ignore lines on -T tar parameter

Tags: bash, tar

I used -T parameter to write the directory inside the file.

```sh
tar -czvf $LOCAL_FILE_SAVE -T $TXT_FILE
```

It's possible ignore the first lines on txt or use a special key to use like comment?

Example:

```
#comment (Ignore this line)
/home/user/stack
```

Comment: Use a tool like `sed`, `awk` or even `find` to generate the desired list of files based on your input file. Then let `tar` [read the files from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use bash's Process Substitution with sed to remove first line:

```
tar -czvf "$LOCAL_FILE_SAVE" -T <(sed 1d "$TXT_FILE")
```

Comment: I assume `sed 1d "$TXT_FILE" | tar -czvf "$LOCAL_SAVE_FILE" -T -` would work just as well, and be more portable to boot.