How could I untar a file and then tar using pipe?
I have a tar file original.tar, and I need to untar it and then re-tar it for some reason. I do not want to untar it to disk and then tar from disk. I hope I can untar the file into stdout, and then tar the files from stdin, I tried this command but failed:
tar xf original.tar -O | tar cf out.tar -T -

But I got plenty of error messages:

Is there any method that I can do this correctly?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin  might provide some options

-T - means that the filenames will be read from stdin; not file contents. There might not be a way to do this using just tar. For the reasons and a possible workaround see Is it possible to make a .tar.gz file directly from stdin? Or, I need to tar together already gzipped files (it is about tgz, not tar, but the reasoning is the same).

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.


I do not want to untar it to disk and then tar from disk. I hope I can untar the file into stdout, and then tar the files from stdin [...]


Is there any method that I can do this correctly?

No, not with the standard tar utility.  It does not accept file data on its standard input, because it needs file metadata along with -- permissions, ownership, timestamps, possibly more.  It gets that from the filesystem. GNU's implementation of tar will accept names of files to archive from its standard input, as an alternative to taking them on the command line, but it will not accept content that way.
You could conceivably write a program to do this, perhaps using something like libtar, though I note that that particular project seems abandoned.
